# How to create interactive hints like this (example inside)

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip, hints

[image]

Hi, i need to create interactive hints.I tried to create *relative* block and position hints inside it (*absolute*) using '%'. But i could not do it.

**Are there any plugins for this or is it simpler to write it myself?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Search for tooltips. They can really come in handy in such a situation.

There are plenty of tooltip plugins on the net, one such is: http://qtip2.com/

Try to implement, play with and customize them.

http://qtip2.com/demos

The above link redirects to one such page where an image is there, and it lets you focus on specific image part to let the tooltip pop in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mzd7maqq/114/

.html

```
<div id="container" class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="img-container">
            <div class="positioning">
                Some Text
            </div>
            <div class="positioningt">
                Some Text
           </div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200/eeeeee" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

.CSS

```
 .col-lg-3{
        width: 25%;
        min-width: 230px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        background-color: #aaa;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .col-lg-3 img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .img-container {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .positioning{
      position: absolute;
      left: 35px;
      top: 22px;
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
      padding: 4px;
      font-size: 17px;
      line-height: 18px;
    }
    .positioningt{
      position: absolute;
      left: 55px;
      top: 60px;
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
      padding: 4px;
      font-size: 17px;
      line-height: 18px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- if you are using bootstrap you can go through this link for bootstrap tooltip [bootstrap tooltip example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp)

  - if you are not using bootstrap then you can use this plugin just for tooltip [click here](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#demos)